# Why prompt returns sometimes null as string

Tags: javascript

a friend of mine asked me why this code doesn't work properly by canceling prompt.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = prompt("Enter your name:", "");
    if (!name) {
        name = "unknown";       
    }
    var ans =("<h2>" + "Hello, "+ name + "!"+"</h2>");      
    document.write(ans);        
</script>
```

Here is jsfidle https://jsfiddle.net/085svr3u/

I found out, that in the example above propmt returns "null" ie. null as string by cancel. And I have no idea why.

I tried to play with original code and refactored it a bit. Now it works as expected. But I still have no explanation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function test() {
        var name = prompt("Enter your name:", "");
        if (!name) {
            name = "unknown";       
        }
        var ans =("<h2>" + "Hello, "+ name + "!"+"</h2>");      
        document.write(ans);        
    }

    test();
</script>
```

And here is modified version https://jsfiddle.net/085svr3u/1/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The word _sometimes_ makes no sense in programming IMO.. Either it does or it does not... The reason of `"null"` could be user had entered `null` as input in `prompt`

Comment: @SLaks the question is, why does `null` become a string.

Comment: You have pasted the same code twice. I guess the first should have been without that `if` statement?

Comment: No he didn't, the second is within a function @nicael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your answer

The keyword '**name**' causes problems when used in global scope in javascript

If even in your first case, you replace 'name' with 'fname' or some other variable name it will stop giving null.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fname = prompt("Enter your name:", "");
    if (!fname) {
        fname = "unknown";      
    }
    var ans =("<h2>" + "Hello, "+ fname + "!"+"</h2>");     
    document.write(ans);        
</script>
```

In the second case variable '**name**' is locally created inside the function and it does not conflict with **window.name**. Hence it works properly

Comment: @nicael Yes it is, and the lesson to be learned here is to keep the use of global variables to a bare minimum.

Comment: Oh lol it is indeed. Sorry for that! I'm stupid.

Answer (score 4):

@RahulArora has basically provided the right answer, but to provide a bit more illumination about what is happening:

Browsers have a built-in global variable called [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) which stores the name of the window. If you assign a value to it, the value you assign will be converted to a string. This has nothing to do with `prompt()`; you can observe it like this:

```
var name = null;
console.log(typeof name);  // "string"
console.log(name.length);  // 4
```

The moral of the story: **Avoid using global variables unless you absolutely have to, and if you do, make sure they're not already being used for something else!**

Comment: Thanks for further clarifying. Much appreciated

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks. I didn't know 'name' would be a global variable. I also didn't know about this 'magic' conversion.

Answer (score -1):

**One line answer to your question is that, it returns null when user has escaped the prompt box by clicking cancel or pressing escape.**

For further clarification of concepts read this :-

This is formal defiinition of function:

```
result = window.prompt(message, default);
```

**result :** is a string containing the text entered by the user, or null.

**message :** is a string of text to display to the user. This parameter is optional and can be omitted if there is nothing to show in the prompt window.

**default :** is a string containing the default value displayed in the text input field. It is an optional parameter. **Note** that in Internet Explorer 7 and 8, if you do not provide this parameter, the string "undefined" is the default value.
(Above was from [Mozilla's definition of prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt))

Now we Conclude that:

prompt() returns either null or "string" which can include ""(empty string).

Now We have three states to inspect:

**null** : The user has clicked Cancel or pressed Esc.

**""(empty string)** : The user clicked OK or pressed Enter with no text input

**"string"** : The user entered some text.

hope it helps...!