# Prompt not returning null?

Tags: javascript

I have a prompt at the beginning of my page, and the text of a header is changed depending on the user's input. Since clicking the *Cancel* button returns null and clicking the *Ok* button without any text entered in the field returns an empty string, I used the two checks in my code to alter the text accordingly. The issue is that the prompt isn't actually returning null when the *Cancel* button is clicked. It is instead returning it as a string.

Javascript:

```
var name = prompt("Enter your name");
var header = document.getElementById("welcome-header");

if (name !== "null" && name !== "") {
    header.innerHTML = `Welcome, ${name}!`;
}
```

To accommodate for this, I had to actually put *null* in a string, as shown in the code snippet. Am I missing something?

[Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) where W3 shows that it should return null.

Comment: Why is the prompt not returning null? if I change the if statement to: if (name !== null) {...} it stops working.

Comment: This is weird, according to the doc it should return `null`

Comment: I was even more confused when I came across the error, because I had recently been utilizing prompts when messing around, and it worked just fine when checking for null values. It doesn't do that here, though

Comment: `window.name`? probably is mixing the global property

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ChrisLallo your code does return `null` when you click the cancel button, it just returns an empty string when you click ok with an empty input https://jsfiddle.net/k0fmwvep/

Comment: **Duplicate, see this question:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597356/why-prompt-returns-sometimes-null-as-string

Comment: Yeah that was the whole issue. Thanks a lot @Ele

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a falsy check:

```
if (!name) {...}
```

Comment: Works fine for null values, but not for when I enter actual strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should not care if it's null, if it's not null it should have a length of > 0  but you can just use simple regex to look for any word in case only blank spaces are entered.  Not sure why null is getting passed as a string, I can't duplicate that behavior but if it's an edge case, try:

```
if (name != 'null' && name.match(/\w/).length > 0 {
    header.innerHTML = `Welcome, ${name}!`;
}
```

Comment: Still allows for null to pass through (clicking "Cancel" displays 'Welcome, null!')

Comment: what browser are you using? that seems odd

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: See comments on the main thread

Comment: @ChrisLallo ok but you will get same problem if someone enters the space bar 2x or more then hit ok, so you'll still have a bug without the regex example I've given here